# Spark - how to `collectAsync` with `DataSet`

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm looking for a way to execute/queue multiple spark sql jobs simultaneously in Java. I understand there are `collect` and `collectAsync` functions for `JavaRDD` objects, but there appears to only be a `collectAsList` function on the `DataSet` class.

Is the expected approach that if you want to do a `collectAsync` that you need to convert your `DataSet` to a `JavaRDD`, or am I missing something?

Note, I am fairly new to spark, so maybe the transformation I described is trivial, but the approach I am looking for is one that limits the number spark jobs I am required to execute on my data set.